# Open the same Java (Qt) program but with the windows in different places

Tags: java, shell, qt

I'm using the 3dmod program of IMOD which is coded in Java (using Qt I think). For my project, I often need to open multiple `.mrc` files (3D reconstruct) as well as the model I've put on it using a command like the following:

```
3dmod -E 1U my_3d_object_part1.mrc my_model_part1.mod
```

After doing all the parts (around 5-10), I need to open all of them to compare.

Are there any ways to create a shell script to do this? Knowing that file names are almost identical, only the number 1 will have to change.

Note that the doc says "3dmod will accept some Qt options (such as -style)". I don't know what those options do or if they can control the window position at launch. I am hoping I could distribute my model windows across my screen to see them all at once.

I am concerned this may not be possible. Are there any ways to control the initial window position at opening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt5 applications can set their initial size/position using the `qwindowgeometry` flag, like this:

```
./myApp -qwindowgeometry 640x480+50+50
```

EDIT:
On Qt4, and I think only if you're using X11, the flag is named `-geometry`.